# PayPal iOS sdk allow user to pay with old credentials even if user changes the password/pin using sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

Our iPad app has been processing payments successfully in sandbox mode using v1.0.5 of the iOS SDK. However, we found one defect while testing our application. Please find steps below.

1. Login into PayPal.
2. Use email or phone and type in your credentials.
3. click on send payment. You will see the payment complete screen. Click on done button.
4. Now open your sandbox account and change the password/pin (Profile->Update password).
5. Then go to the application and try to make payment again. PayPal sdk navigate you directly   to the confirmation page.
6. Click on send Payment.

PayPal SDK allow user to pay with old credentials(password/pin).

Is this a known issue or I am missing anything?

Also is there any way to log out user after every payment. (Force user to login every time he tries to make the payment without manually clicking logout button).

Comment: how to know phone number and pin in the sandbox mode

Answer (score 1):

moka, I think that the scenario you describe is okay as is.

Within your app, the user logs in to her PayPal account, pays you, and chooses to not log out from PayPal.

Later, within your app she remains logged in to her PayPal account, even though elsewhere she has changed her password. And therefore she can still pay you from this account.

That all seems fine to me.

Regarding your second question:

When you call *[PayPalPaymentViewController initWithClientId:receiverEmail:payerId:payment:delegate:]*, the SDK uses the *payerId* to determine whether this is a new user or a returning user.

So if you change the *payerId* each time you call the SDK, then each time this will be interpreted as a new user, who will therefore require a fresh PayPal login. (For example, you could set *payerId* to something like *[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rand()]*.)

-- Dave Goldman (eBay/PayPal/card.io)

Comment: @moka I just happened again upon this conversation. In the past couple of months we fixed a relevant bug, so there is now a simpler answer to your question: If you do NOT provide a `payerId`, then the user will be considered a fresh user, and will therefore be required to log in.

Answer (score 1):

Set `rememberUser` property to `NO` for **PayPalConfiguration** instance like this

```
payPalConfiguration=[[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];
payPalConfiguration.rememberUser=NO;
```

It will then ask each time to login.